# Atualizar página automaticamente?

Tags: css, servidor, html

Estou com um site na web, e faço constantes atualizações.

Porem  após essas atualizações no servidor, o site não atualiza sozinho nos dispositivos/desktop, preciso pressionar CTRL + F5 para atualizar.

O problema é que nem todo mundo vai dar CTRL + F5 antes de utilizar o site, gostaria de saber se existe algum forma de arrumar esse problema.

Exemplo:

Tenho um layout VERDE na web.

Mudo no css(local) para VERMELHO e mando essa atualização para o servidor.

Se eu NÃO apertar CTRL + F5 depois de realizar a mudança, meu site na web vai continuar com o layout VERDE.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<meta http-equiv="Cache-Control" content="no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate">
<meta http-equiv="Pragma" content="no-cache">
<meta http-equiv="Expires" content="0">
```

Comment: Como é chamado esse tipo de problema? essas meta-tags resolveram meu problema, obrigado

Comment: @NicolasGuilhermeMatheus é apenas Cache. Não necessariamente um problema!

Answer (score 1):

A um tempo atrás eu havia criado uma função que basicamente pega o horário local na máquina e atualiza o script/css para usar a versão daquele horário.

Segue a função

```
    function getStringDate() {
    var data = (+new Date());

        horario= ('?_='+ data),
        str = $('.c').attr('href'),
        fimstr = str+horario;
        console.log(fimstr);
        $('.s').attr('href',fimstr);
}
```

No seu document ready faça a chamada

```
setInterval(getStringDate,10000);
```

Nesse caso o script fica verificando a cada 10 segundos e adicionando o tempo no final do href do seu css. Para usar, adicione a classe "c" nos links que precisar, e caso precise usar em script, basta alterar de href para src no script.

Comment: Obrigado pela solução Jorge, porem não deixaria meu site lento? ficar verificando a todo momento :s

Comment: @NicolasGuilhermeMatheus essa seria uma solução mais específicas para   determinados links que você citasse, em relação á lentidão: como seria feito apenas a cada 10s e quando o usuário estivesse na página, não haveria problema, no caso em que você não queira guardar o cache, independente do arquivo, o uso das metas tag citadas pelo Amadeu é o mais adequado.

Comment: aaa, entendi, mas de qualquer forma, eu agradeço por tentar me ajudar de alguma maneira ^^.

Answer (score 1):

Se não conseguir evitar o CACHE você pode fazer com PHP (imagino que seja o que usa na sua hospedagem) para gerar um número que nunca se repete, aconselho usar DATA e HORA para que o navegador interprete como URLs diferentes através de uma variável.

O formato não será notado como data e hora, eu coloquei no exemplo somente até minutos e não segundos pra não gerar uma sobre carga desnecessária de acesso à sua hospedagem.

Colque isso no começo do código.

```
<?php
$nc = "?".date('YmdHi'); //Exemplo do resultado 201802061040
?>
```

Exemplos:

```
<script src="seuscript.js<?php echo $nc ?>"></script>

<img src="imagem.jpg<?php echo $nc ?>" />
```

Isso afetará apenas conteúdos colocados em HTML, se o visitante acessar urls de arquivos de de texto/db (*.TXT, *.LOG, *.JSON) ou imagens diretamente digitadas na barra do navegador verá apenas a primeira versão do arquivo até que o CACHE expire.

Nesse caso aconselho a modificar o HTACESS da sua hospedagem, isso tornará qualquer código dispensável:

```
<filesMatch "\.(html|htm|js|css|png|gif|jpg|jpeg|json)$">
FileETag None
<ifModule mod_headers.c>
Header unset ETag
Header set Cache-Control "max-age=0, no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate"
Header set Pragma "no-cache"
Header set Expires "Wed, 11 Jan 1984 05:00:00 GMT"
</ifModule>
</filesMatch>
```